# How do i refer to the $(this) element insidea $.post

Tags: jquery, this

I have this code

```
    $.post("recommend.php",{"jid":jid,"vid":vid,"eid":eid},function(data){
        if(data=="1")
            {
                $(this).text("Recommended");

            }
            else
                {
                    $(thelink).text("Recommend");
                }
    });
```

the post is executed properly but the text on the link is NOT changing though data is equal to 1. Any help...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`this` refers to the current context. In your AJAX callback it is different from the one of your calling function.

However, you can simply preserve it by using `var $this = $(this);` and then use `$this` inside the callback instead of `$(this)`;

```
var $this = $(this);
$.post("recommend.php", {
    "jid": jid,
    "vid": vid,
    "eid": eid
}, function (data) {
    if (data == "1") {
        $this.text("Recommended");
    } else {
        $(thelink).text("Recommend");
    }
});
```

Of course another name would work, too. For example to preserve a plain `this` lots of people use `self` or `that`.

Another solution would be using `$.ajax({ context: this, ...... }));` to keep the same context inside the callback (if unspecified, `this` points to the options object passed to `$.ajax()`)

Answer (score 3):

Set it to a variable before calling `$.post`

```
var that = $(this);
$.post(..., function() {
    that.myFunction();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

By default, `this` inside an AJAX callback is the `jqXHR` object for the request.

You should either cache the reference to the link (as you appear to have done with `thelink`) or use the `context` option to `$.ajax`:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "recommend.php",
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
        "jid": jid,
        "vid": vid,
        "eid": eid
    },
    context: this,
    success: function (data) {
        if (data == "1") {
            $(this).text("Recommended");

        } else {
            $(thelink).text("Recommend");
        }
    }
});
```

The `context` option sets the context for the callback functions -- i.e. it defines `this` within them. By setting it to the outer value of `this` (the reference to the link), you can access the link with `$(this)` within the callback.